# Finding matched values in dictionary with list?

Tags: c#-4.0, dictionary, generic-list

I have the following dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, List<TypeA>> dict
```

And have added objects:

```
dict.Add(1, new List<TypeA>{TypeA.1, TypeA.2, TypeA.3};
dict.Add(11, new List<TypeA>{TypeA.2, TypeA.6, TypeA.7};
dict.Add(23, new List<TypeA>{TypeA.3, TypeA.4, TypeA.9};
```

Using a single line of syntax (lambdas), how do I find any TypeA.3 in the entire dictionary?

This will be encapsulated into a method that returns a bool.  True == match and false == no match.  The above would return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some working code inspired by Reed.

You can pop this into LINQPad and see it run.  Get LINQPad at http://linqpad.com it helps!

```
    static bool CheckIT(Dictionary<int, List<TypeA>> theList, TypeA what)
    {
        return theList.Any(dctnry => dctnry.Value.Any(lst => lst == what));
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

        dict.Add(1, new List<TypeA>{TypeA.1, TypeA.2, TypeA.3};
        dict.Add(11, new List<TypeA>{TypeA.2, TypeA.6, TypeA.7};
        dict.Add(23, new List<TypeA>{TypeA.3, TypeA.4, TypeA.9};

        if (CheckIT(dict,TypeA.3 ))
         Console.WriteLine("Found");
        else
          Console.WriteLine("Lost");
    }
```

You can also take this one step more and make a generic version such as

```
    static bool CheckIT<T>(Dictionary<int, List<T>> theList, T what) where T : IEquatable<T>
    {
        return theList.Any(dict => dict.Value.Any(l => l.Equals(what)));
    }
```

then you would say

```
   if (CheckIT<TypeA>(dict,TypeA.3 ))
```

but you could also say

```
   if (CheckIT<int>(dict,13 ))
```

as I did since I did not have TypeA defined.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to see if `TypeA.3` exists anywhere, you could use:

```
bool exists = dict.Values.Any(v => v.Any(t => t == TypeA.3));
```